# MapView: Tapping annotation gives me wrong detail view data?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using an NSDictionary to populate data for my MapView annotations. However, when I tap on my MapView annotation, the detailView should display the selected user's information. That said, right now, when I tap an annotation, all detailViews display the same user's information (even though the details in the actual annotation's display bubble are correct). How can I fix this? Why won't NSDictionary allow me to do this?

**MapViewController.m**

```
    NSMutableDictionary *viewParams = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [viewParams setValue:@"u000" forKey:@"view_name"];
    [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        self.addressData = [responseObject mutableCopy];


        for (NSMutableDictionary *multiplelocations in self.addressData) {

            NSString *location = multiplelocations[@"street_address"];
            NSLog(@"Pull addresses %@", location);
            NSString *userNames = multiplelocations[@"users_name"];
            NSString *userBio = multiplelocations[@"userbio"];


        CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
        [geocoder geocodeAddressString:location
                     completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                        if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                             CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                             MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];

                             MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapView.region;

                             region.span.longitudeDelta /= 8.0;
                             region.span.latitudeDelta /= 8.0;


                            MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
                            point.coordinate = placemark.coordinate;
                            point.title = userNames;
                            point.subtitle = userBio;

                            [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];



                            }
                     }



         ];

        }


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];


}

 -(void)calloutTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    NSLog(@"Callout was tapped");



    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    OtherUserViewController *yourViewController = (OtherUserViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OtherUserViewController"];

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    dictionary = [[self.addressData firstObject] mutableCopy];

    yourViewController.mapuserData = dictionary; 


   [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];

}
```

**self.addressData via console**

```
 {
        address = "1300 Fake Street, Vancouver, BC";
        childrenunder = No;
        city = Va;
        "emergency facility" = Yes;
        "first name" = Admin;
        "last name" = Account;
        phone = "Not Available";
        "photo_path" = "http://myurl.com/files/stored/1461176121.jpg";
        "postal code" = V6B0L1;
        "profile photo" = "<img typeof=\"foaf:Image\" src=\"stored/1461176121.jpg\" width=\"300\" height=\"300\" alt=\"\" />";
        "property type" = House;
        province = B;
        "street_address" = "1300 Fake Street, Vancouver, BC";
        supervision = Yes;
        uid = 1;
        userbio = "Need assistance? This account belongs to the team! Message us if you have any questions.";
        "users_name" = Britt;
    }
)
```

Comment: Add the code of detail view navigation.

Comment: @Subramanian See edit :)

Comment: While navigating to detail view controller, you are always getting the first object from the dictionary array. `[[self.addressData firstObject] mutableCopy];` Thats the reason you are getting the same information for all the annotation view

Comment: @Subramanian Omg, lol.... Thank you. Ok, so what should that line look like instead? I assume I need mutableCopy in order to pass it to the next view (if I remove it, it says incompatible pointer types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While navigating to detail view controller, you are always getting the first object from the dictionary array.

**`[[self.addressData firstObject] mutableCopy];`**

Thats the reason you are getting the same information for all the annotation view.

Instead of that line of code, You have to identify which map marker is clicked on the `MapView`, for example identify the index of the dictionary array. Pick the dictionary from the array and pass it to the detail view.

Answer (score 1):

```
dictionary = [[self.addressData firstObject] mutableCopy];
```

Are you serious?

This should be

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [self.addressData  mutableCopy];
```

Comment: FML - NO idea why I had firstObject in there. Thank you... Lol

Comment: That said, changing it to your suggestion causes my app to crash? I get: [__NSArrayI objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174672300

Comment: Well, do that in one line. I was being silly to answer fast. See the edit

Comment: Strangely enough, that change now causes a crash in my detailView. At this line: self.username.text = self.mapuserData[@"users_name"]; Sorry for my "newb-ness" - tried changing that line to valueForKey and I still get the crash. That said, I can't tell if your line actually works yet :/

Comment: See edit :) Thanks for your help - it's appreciated!

Comment: You don't have a key named `users_name` in your dictionary. So how are you expecting any value for this key?

Comment: I do... I just copied half of the console output (structure is the same). See full above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147881/discussion-between-nayem-and-brittany).